# Need to scan row horizontally and compare data with other table and get max ID's data as a result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to compare data horizontally and compare that data with other table's record and need to get data of Max(ID) for that row.

Here is the scenario:

I have a table which is containing data of color:

[image]

In this image Every color has their ID...

Here is the image of Table that has data for clas info:

[image]

So, Required output is:

[image]

Explanation of Output:

If you check the second image which has data for class::

I need to check only that columns which has Color at the end of column name

In this scenario we have 3 columns: Maths_color, Science_Color, Physics_Color

I need to get the output as Max(ID) of that color

for example: for Class_ID 1 we have White, Yellow, White

Means ID for White is 1, for Yellow is 3 so Output for Class_ID 1 is Yellow

for Clas_ID 2 we have white, Red, Green Means White is 1, Red is 4 and Green is 2 so the output is Red

I got this output but it is static...I need dynamic Output because it is possibility that in future we are going to change the order of color...so, based on that order of color output also needs to change.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
DECLARE @COLOR VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
( CLASS_ID INT,
CLASS_COLOR VARCHAR(50))

SELECT
@COLOR = COALESCE(@COLOR + '+', '') + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Class_Info' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%COLOR'

SET @SQL = 
'INSERT #TEMP
 SELECT Clas_ID
        ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''RED'','+ @COLOR +') <> 0  THEN ''RED''
              WHEN CHARINDEX(''YELLOW'', '+ @COLOR + ') <> 0 THEN ''YELLOW''
              WHEN CHARINDEX(''GREEN'', '+@COLOR + ') <> 0 THEN ''GREEN''    
              WHEN CHARINDEX(''WHITE'', ' + @COLOR + ') <> 0 THEN ''WHITE''
              ELSE ''NO_COLOR'' END AS CLASS_COLOR
FROM 
Class_Info'

Execute(@SQL)
select * from #TEMP
```

Can anyone suggest me some way that how can I compare color with ID and get max(id)'s color in output.

Note: I can not use column name from my Class_info table because in future we can delete or add more columns... So, I need to have dynamic query that give me perfect result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 CREATE TABLE #tb_color(ID INT ,color VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO #tb_color
    SELECT 1,'White' UNION
    SELECT 2,'Green' UNION
    SELECT 3,'Yellow' UNION
    SELECT 4,'Red'
CREATE TABLE #tb_class(Class_ID INT ,Class VARCHAR(100),Maths_Color VARCHAR(100),Science_color VARCHAR(100),Phasic_color VARCHAR(100),Class_welth VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #tb_class
    SELECT 1,'1st sem','White','Yellow','White','Fair' UNION
    SELECT 2,'2nd sem','White','Red','Green','Bad' UNION
    SELECT 3,'3rd sem','Green','White','White','Good' UNION
    SELECT 4,'4th sem','Yellow','Green','Yellow','Fair' UNION
    SELECT 5,'5th sem','White','White','White','Best' UNION
    SELECT 6,'6th sem','Green','Yellow','White','Fair' UNION
    SELECT 7,'7th sem','Yellow','White','White','Fair' UNION
    SELECT 8,'8th sem','Green','Yellow','Red','Bad' 
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',(','(')+QUOTENAME(c.name) +')'
FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c WHERE c.object_id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tb_class') AND  c.name NOT IN  ('Class_ID','Class','Class_welth')
PRINT @cols
SET @sql='
SELECT t.Class_ID,c.color FROM (
    SELECT tc.Class_ID,MAX(c.ID) AS MaxID
    FROM #tb_class AS tc
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES'+@cols+') n(color)
    INNER JOIN #tb_color AS c ON c.color=n.color
    GROUP BY tc.Class_ID
) AS t INNER JOIN #tb_color AS c ON c.ID=t.MaxID'
EXEC(@sql)
```

```
Class_ID    color
----------- ------
1           Yellow
2           Red
3           Green
4           Yellow
5           White
6           Yellow
7           Yellow
8           Red
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need query dynamic...This database is just an example...I can not use column name because in future we can delete or add columns and also there are some table in which we have more than 20 columns which has colors so,it needs to be dynamic query....Thanks for your effort....

Comment: ....Thanks for your answer..I updated some things but it works very well...Thanks for your support...Thank you very much